# How to lock Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens

My Samsung Galaxy S2 locks after some time I don't touch the screen.

How could I lock it immediately, without waiting for this time to pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my original SGS you do it by just clicking the power button.  I would assume it's the same for the SGS2.